# Pythonic way to handle updating status string between functions?

Tags: python

This seems like a remedial topic, but I'm a bit unsure of how to deal with this.  Every solution I think of seems messy.

I'm working with some code that builds up a message while performing several actions, then ultimately returns that msg with an http response.  Currently it looks somewhat like this:

```
try:
    pdict = parser.parseProtocol(id)
    msg = "parsing worked"
except:
    msg = "parsing failed"

try:
    file = parser.getFile(pdict['filePath'])
    msg += "file retrieved"
except:
    msg += "file not found"
```

Say I want to encapsulate the code into functions.  How could do I have a message that gets updated throughout?  Strings are immutable, so I can't just pass them to a function and modify them.  A super ugly solution would be:

```
(pdict, msg) = parseSomething()
if pdict:
    (file, msg) = retrieveFile(pdict, msg)

def parseSomething():
    try:
        pdict = parser.parseProtocol(id)
        return (pdict, "parsing worked")
    except:
        return (None, "parsing failed")

def retrieveFile(pdict, msg)
    try:
        file = parser.getFile(pdict['filePath'])
        return (file, msg + "file retrieved")
    except:
        return (None, msg + "file not found")
```

Super ugly.

I could create a message class, or use a list of length 1, and that would be prettier, but still not very pythonic, right?  I think I just want these functions to take a message string and modify it, without having to return it, but strings are immutable so that's not the default behavior.

There's gotta be a smooth way to do this that I'm just blanking on.  Help?

Comment: your (file, msg) approach doesn't seem that bad.

Comment: Why make your life difficult with these "pythonic" things? I'd just choose the way that takes the least code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider putting your messages in a list and appending to it as you go?

```
messages = []
try:
    pdict = parser.parseProtocol(id)
    messages.append("parsing worked")
except:
    messages.append("parsing failed")

try:
    file = parser.getFile(pdict['filePath'])
    messages.append("file retrieved")
except:
    messages.append("file not found")

print '\n'.join(messages)
```

If your codepath is particularly convuluted, consider embedding them in a class:

```
class Tests(object):
    def __init__(self):
        messages = []
        self.pdict = None

    def parsetest(self):
        try:
            self.pdict = parser.parseProtocol(id)
        except:
            self.messages.append("parsing failed")
        else:
            self.messages.append("parsing worked")

    def retrievetest(self):
        if self.pdict is None:
            raise Exception("called retrievetest() before successfully parsing")
        try:
            file = parser.getFile(self.pdict['filePath'])
        except:
            self.messages.append("file not found")
        else:
            self.messages.append("file retrieved")
```

And then later:

```
tests = Tests()
tests.parsetest()
if condition:
    tests.retrievetest()
print '\n'.join(tests.messages)
```

Answer (score 1):

put your message in an array, pass it around, and just append each part to it.

just before sending it, do a ''.join(msg).

Answer (score 1):

Make your message a member of a class, and pass around an instance of the class.

Better yet, make all these function methods on a class, and keep the message as an attribute of the object.